# How to add a option in right click menu on ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, glade

I am making an app for ubuntu 12.04.What i want to do is add an option to the menubar which  appear when we right click on some select option.

**To make it more  clear-**

---

In Normally when we select some text and right click there appear some option like 
cut 
copy 
paste
I want to add another option how can i do it.

When clicked the option would just have to execute another application and send the selected data to that applicaion.

I would be using Glade with python for development.

Comment: you need to provide more information about your environment. For example, what GUI-Toolkit are you using?

Comment: @niko i would be using Glade with python 2.7

Comment: @msvalkon i have written the main app in python and i didnt really know how to go about integrating it with right click thing.

Answer (score 1):

you should know some basics about glade and gtk first. the following is just notes:

> 1-On glade you can use the menu button to create menu.
>
> 2-Right click on it an dchoose "edit ..."
>
> 3-from the window you can add items.(the right part display the name and type of the menu item , the left part display the properties of the selected item, the lower part display the signals which could connected to the menu item)
>
> 4- now connect the menu item with the function which do what you want (When clicked the option would just have to execute another application and send the selected data to that applicaion.)
>
> 5- go to your code. get the menu as usual .

```
self.menu = self.builder.get_object("menu")
```

> 6- to popup the menu on right click on an object, you should connect that object with the function ahich execute the menu ( assuming that its name is :on_button_press ) :

```
def on_button_press(self, treeview, event):
    if event.button == 3:

        x = int(event.x)

        y = int(event.y)

        time = event.time

        pthinfo = treeview.get_path_at_pos(x, y)

        if pthinfo is not None:

            path, col, cellx, celly = pthinfo

            treeview.grab_focus()

            treeview.set_cursor( path, col, 0)

            self.popupmenu.popup( None, None, None, event.button, time)

        return True
```